# Trouble with button pushes outside of app

Tags: vb.net, spy++

Using Spy++ I've been trying to control form buttons on an external program with my own program.. [image]

The picture shows what control I am attempting to mimic and here's my following code below...

```
    Dim hWnd As IntPtr = FindWindow(vbNullString, ListView4.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(3).Text)
    If hWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
        Return
    End If
    Dim hWndButton As IntPtr = _
    FindWindowEx(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "Load Settings")
    If hWndButton.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
        Return
    End If
```

However nothing happens when I run the code.. one possibility is the window name I'm grabbing is wrong, but if that's not the case is my code correct?

Comment: This code does nothing, so nothing happens...

Comment: aww no wonder.. lol.. thanks for pointing that out. I got it working now.

Comment: What a pity I didn't post this as an answer... It could be my most amusing answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as Alex pointed out, I wasn't actually initiating the button press.. now that he pointed that out I was able to fix my code.. Here's what I now use:

```
Private Declare Auto Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" ( _
ByVal lpClassName As String, _
ByVal lpWindowName As String _
) As IntPtr

Private Declare Auto Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32.dll" ( _
ByVal hwndParent As IntPtr, _
ByVal hwndChildAfter As IntPtr, _
ByVal lpszClass As String, _
ByVal lpszWindow As String _
) As IntPtr

Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
Private Const BM_CLICK = &HF5


    Dim hwndParent As Long = FindWindow(vbNullString, ListView4.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(3).Text)
    Debug.Print("findwindow: " & hwndParent)
    Dim hwndButton As Long = FindWindowEx(hwndParent, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "Save as")
    Debug.Print("OK: " & hwndButton)
    hwndButton = SendMessage(hwndButton, BM_CLICK, 0, 0)
    Debug.Print("Clicked: " & hwndButton)
```